# Most Effiecient Thread Implmentation IOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-audio

I've been trying to find a thread implementation in IOS that suits my projects needs. So far I've failed to find an acceptable solution.

My Problem :

I need to read audio from up to 16 mp3 files on disk simultaneously.

What I have tried:

First off I tried using a **NSTimer** witch repeats. The timer was not fast enough and the audio would drop out when I played any more than 4 files.

Second I tried Using an **NSThread** with a priority of 1. The audio just about played correctly but the UI Became wholly unresponsive.

Finally I tried dispatching blocks using **GCD** in my callback whenever I needed more audio from a file. Again the audio would drop out but the UI was responsive.

In all three of the examples above I also tried dividing up the work load by creating 4 threads and having each thread handle 4 audio files each but this caused really bad synchronization problems with the audio.

Are there other thread options that I can try or do the above sum up what IOS has to offer?

Do you think that reading from 16 files from disk simultaneously is too much of a strain for the IOS system?

Is there a limit of how many threads IOS can handle?

To avoid making my question sound like a discussion I will summarize as follows.

What IOS thread technology is best suited for very frequent calling, quickly completing execution, that can be easily synchronized and will not impact on UI responsiveness.

Any anecdotal advice from solving a similar audio programming problem is also appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

This is some stripped down code I modelled on a suggestion from a so user. All I'm after solid advice on what setup is going to work best for me. Since my last post I tried NSThread and it does seem to leave me with audio dropouts. Also I tried using NSConditions so that my thread is wasting processing power when its not filling buffer but using these locks seems like a real bad idea for audio callbacks.

```
OSStatus channelMixerCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                              AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                              const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                              UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                              UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                              AudioBufferList *ioData) { 


    AudioInfo = myaudio[inBusNumber];

    if(myaudio.needsbufferfill==YES)

    {
        [refToSelf performSelector:@selector(GetAudioForItem:) onThread:engineDescribtion.producerthread withObject:myaudio waitUntilDone:false];

    }





}

-(void) startthread

{
    engineDescribtion.producerthread =[[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(dosinglerunloop) object:nil];

    [engineDescribtion.producerthread start];



}

-(void)dosinglerunloop
{
    BOOL isstarted=YES;
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    do {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];

    } while (isstarted);


    [pool release];

}


- (void)GetAudioForItem:(AudioInfo *)info
{

    // use data in Audio Info to seek to
    //corrent place in file
    //and extract audio to buffers

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 0:**

Your audio render callbacks should never lock. Example: Creating a single heap allocation will lock.

---

Your threads will all compete for the hardware. To keep the UI responsive, you should not have many *highest priority* threads (the audio playback should be the only one). Consider the number of cores, disks, etc you have available in your design.

If you still have issues once you have correctly fixed that: Loading short files into memory can offload some of the disk's demand to memory.

You should profile to determine what is actually the problem: It may be CPU *or* I/O. You may be simply missing your render deadlines and equating audio dropouts to "can't read fast enough". If you are using a lot of CPU, then Disk I/O may not be the problem. Decoding and performing sample rate conversion on 16 mp3 files can require relatively high CPU (as one example of the things you need to look for).

pthreads will be *fastest*, but will require some work to implement right. That really doesn't matter at this time because there seem to be a few high level issues yet and there are multiple APIs which should handle the task just fine.

Your program should be smart enough to detect when read buffers cannot be filled fast enough.

You are pre filling the buffers, correct?

Presumably, you are using a run loop?

Comment: could you please explain "single heap allocation" to me?

Comment: @dubbeat `void* a = malloc(1);` and `NSObject * obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];` are both examples of things that create a heap allocation.

Comment: Yeah Im prefilling by buffers. Each buffer is broken into 2 parts, A and B. A fills while B is being read and B fills while A is being read.(I couldnt implement CARingbuffer correctly) The buffer size is 100 * the callback number of frames (512). I've never used a run loop for this, Only the methods I described above.

Comment: @dubbeat Run loops can be used to pause the reader thread's execution when there is no reading to perform (read: if it always ran, then you could overwrite data you have prepared but not yet played back). I'm not fond of the CA Public APIs, but I have solved most of these problems myself. Considering your experience, I'd recommend that you use them (e.g. `CARingBuffer`) where applicable, rather than reinventing concepts which take several years to master and implement. Reuse them in your programs, but don't consider them a good model to learn from if you want to write modern C++ audio designs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's only one disk… So any solution that requires 16 simultaneous reads might be an issue. (Depending on if you're I/O bound or CPU bound.)

NSTimer is not going to get you consistent results.

I don't see any reason why NSThread would kill UI responsiveness, perhaps you had a bug.

Comment: If an NSThread is very CPU intensive and taking a long time to execute could that potentially take processing time away from the main thread? I was using detatchnewthreadselector with a priority of 1.0

Comment: Well sure, any thread that's processing takes time from the main thread. But the main thread shouldn't need 100% of the CPU to remain responsive. Over-prioritizing might be the issue, I haven't played with that. I doubt a single thread would overwhelm the UI thread though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with this system being disk-bound because 16 channels of MP3 is no problem CPU-wise on modern machines - how much rattling is coming from your box?  I would probably be tempted to use just one thread to fill the empty buffers with the buffer sized to accommodate, (averageDiskLatency*(bytes/msec)*16*bodgeFactor) bytes of audio stream, (bodgeFactor means rounded up to 8K boundary and add a few 8K's).  Whenever threads/callbacks/whatever empty a buffer and so start on the other one, they should queue the empty buffer to the disk read thread, (thread-safe producer-consumer queue), to get it filled up again.  Probably, each buffer should include a 'fileControl' instance containing the the fileSpec, file handle, state variable for EOF etc, error string space and anything else needed for the read thread to work as well as the buffer space itself.

This design allows the disk to read nice, large chunks without being annoyingly preempted half-way through reads and being avoidably forced to move lumps of metal too often.

Rgds,
Martin

PS - If you haven't got one already, get an SSD - works wonders for multi-channel audio/video latency.

Comment: @Martin. I edited my question with some stripped down code which I think is based on your suggestion. Could you advise me if this is loosely what you had in mind? (I have no working solution yet)